# Deleted every user in Windows 8.1 and now it asks to log in to them

Tags: windows-8.1, user-accounts

Today, I deleted every user from Windows 8.1 hoping that it wouldn't require a password to log on. After the restart it asked me to log in to my account and 2 different ones. I tried logging into mine, but I got `Username or password is incorrect` even though everything is correct.

Comment: How did you delete the users exactly ? If you deleted every single user profile on your computer, I'm not sure you will be able to log in again

Comment: via "User Accounts", netplwiz

Comment: Maybe too late now, but on a local account (only) you can remove the password http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/disable-remove-password (near bottom). But if you've deleted the *users* I agree there may be no way to signin at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you have deleted all users, how you can be able to login, You can be able in condition if the Guest account is active.
You can see this [link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-security/how-do-i-restore-a-deleted-user-account-in-windows/7e329d5f-fda4-4407-a1f4-0e0e02b9179b) if it can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In windows it is not possbile that any of the account doesn't exist because you can not delete the account in which you currently logged in and there always have administrator account which is same as root account in Linux based os.  so try to login into the administartor account and even if you canot login try to crack the passowrd. for cracking password reffer this link:

http://pethaniakshay.blogspot.in/2015/07/crack-windows-password-in-2-minute-or_1.html